# Styling axis text: is this the best (or only) way to do it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to style the axis date/time text to make the day breaks more prominent.

[image]

Based on a bunch of QAs here I came up with the function below. I am working on a timeline based on the [Brush & Zoom example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) so I am calling this function on every brush and zoom event.

The timeline is still performant but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. I haven't been using `d3` (or JS, for that matter) very long so I'm sometimes still cobbling things together without entirely understanding what is going on and what possible ramifications may result.

---

```
function styleAxis() {
    d3.selectAll('g.tick')
        .select('text')
        .style('fill', function (d) {
            var txt = d3.select(this).text().split(" ");
            var days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

            if (days.indexOf(txt[0]) != -1) {
                return "white"
            } else {
                return "gray"
            }
        });
}
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: i would use js to set an atrtrib on the special tags only, then hit it in css; faster rendering (css runs in C), better separation, and easier to add additional styles later w/ media queries et al...

Answer (score 0):

Just to save you some lines of code, you can select the text element inside `tickFormat` (despite that not being the purpose of `tickFormat`) using `this`, when you define your line generator, and apply the style you want:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d === "bar") {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "gray")
    }
    return d;
  });
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([20, 280])
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d === "bar") {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "gray")
    }
    return d;
  });
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)");
axis(gX);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

In your example, your style depends on the data. On the other hand, if the style doesn't depend on the data (for instance, when you want to apply the same style for all the ticks), the alternative is even shorter: just apply the style to the containing `<g>` element.

Therefore, your approach is not the only one. Regarding it being the *best* one I prefer not saying anything, since this is opinion based and depends on several factors.